# How to make dataguard switchover seamlessly

Tags: oracle, dataguard

In my Dataguard configuration on a 12c environment, when I perform a switchover from primary (`foo`) to standby (`bar`) and then try to sqlplus in with `user@foo`, I receive the "`ORA-011033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress`" error instead of being able to connect to the new primary(bar).

Now, I know that this is because the connection is still pointing to the `foo` address instead of the `bar` address, and according to many articles, you need to create a new "virtual" service to handle the different connections, as well as a trigger to stop/start this service after a rolechange.

I did this and with the `service_names` parameter set to this new "virtual" service, a switchover will work and can also switch back but when trying to sqlplus with `user@foo` it throws `ORA-011033`. The trigger is useless and the service continues to run on both foo and bar because it seems that having that parameter set overrides whatever the trigger tries to do.

Now if I don't define that parameter, my switchover works fine, and the triggers do their job, and when I `sqlplus user@foo`, it will correctly redirect me to the `bar` address. However, when I try to switchover back to `foo`, I receive the following in the DG alert log:

`Redo transport problem detected: redo transport to database foo has the following error:

ORA-16047: DGID mismatch between destination setting and target database
08/05/2016 16:01:02 
Initialization of connection failed. 
Expected destination db_unique_name is foo.
Database actually reached is bar 
Failed to send message to site foo. Error code is ORA-16642. 
Data Guard Broker Status Summary:

Type                        Name                             Severity  Status
  Configuration               foo_dg                         Warning  ORA-16607
  Primary Database            bar                            Error  ORA-16778
  Physical Standby Database   foo                              Error  ORA-16642`

ON FOO:

> log_archive_dest_2='service="bar"','ASYNC NOAFFIRM delay=0 optional
>   compression=disable max_failure=0 max_connections=1 reopen=300
>   db_unique_name="bar"
>   net_timeout=30','valid_for=(online_logfile,all_roles)'
>   fal_client='foo' fal_server='bar'

ON BAR:

> log_archive_dest_2='service="foo", ASYNC NOAFFIRM delay=0 optional
>   compression=disable max_failure=0 max_connections=1 reopen=300
>   db_unique_name="foo" valid_for=(online_logfile,all_roles)'
>   fal_client='bar' fal_server='foo'

Entries in LDAP:
foo:

> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=foo_home)(PORT=15940))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bar_home)(PORT=15940)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=virtual_foo)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=SESSION)(METHOD=basic))))

bar:

> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bar_home)(PORT=15940)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=bar)))

I'm not sure what I'm missing or misunderstanding. Can anyone shed any light as to what I might be doing wrong? Can provide more info if needed.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146188/how-to-make-dataguard-switchover-seamlessly.